# Extra margin being added in responsive grid

Tags: css

I am creating a responsive grid to display images and other info.

I posted an [example in codepen](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/pzgux/?editors=110). Basically I have **2 problems**:

1. When I resize the window to the smallest size (1 column) I get a right margin which should not exist.
2. Independently of the size the last row always gets a bottom margin.

The markup is the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>    
</div>
```

And the CSS (LESS) is:

```
.wrapper {

  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 5%;
  .clear;

  div {

    background-color: green;
    float: left;  

    .make(@count) {

      margin: 0 (6 / (@count - 1) * 1%) (6 / (@count - 1) * 1%) 0;
      width: (94 / @count) * 1%;

      &:nth-child(@{count}n) {margin-right: 0;}

    } // make

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {.make(1);}

    @media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {.make(2);}

    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {.make(3);}

    @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {.make(4);}

    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      outline: 0;
    }

  }

}

.clear {

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  } // :after

} // clear
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at my [PocketGrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/) micro grid framework, it will make your life easier! ;)

It's a pure CSS grid but you can also use it with LESS.

I made a CodePen for you:
http://codepen.io/arnaudleray/pen/HgweL?editors=110

The **HTML** is the same as yours:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>    
</div>
```

Then you can **import PocketGrid at the beginning of your LESS file** (please let the Copyright):

```
//@import (less) "http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/pocketgrid.css"

/*! PocketGrid 1.1.0
* Copyright 2013 Arnaud Leray
* MIT License
*/
/* Border-box-sizing */
.block-group, .block, .block-group:after, .block:after, .block-group:before, .block:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clearfix */
.block-group {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.block-group:before, .block-group:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.block-group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.block-group {
  /* ul/li compatibility */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Nested grid */
.block-group > .block-group {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

/* Default block */
.block {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

After that, you can set your classes in the LESS file:
your `.wrapper` must extend `.block-group`, and your child divs must extend `.block`.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  &:extend(.block-group);

  background-color: red;

  div {
    &:extend(.block);

    background-color: green;

    img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }

}

.make(@count) {
  .wrapper div {
    width: (100% / @count);
  }

  // PocketGrid can manage gutters in pixels, percents or even ems...
  @gutter: 10px * @count;

  .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
  .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
} // make


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { .make(1); }

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) { .make(2); }

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px)  { .make(3); }

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) { .make(4); }
```

You can have more examples about PocketGrid here: http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/

Hope this helps!

Comment: You code is not working. Please check http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/AyaCt/. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to import the PocketGrid source **at the beginning of your LESS file**, not at the end: it should work.

Comment: Arnaul, it seems the way you implemented PocketGrid only allows one grid per page, not?

Comment: No, you can have **as many PocketGrid block-group as you want** in your pages, **you can even nest them**.  


Here is an example of nested grid in the PocketGrid doc: http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#nested-grids  


And the PocketGrid site itself is built with many PocketGrid grids. For example, you can view the source of the home page: http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing the Right Margin Issue**

If you inspect the CSS generated by the LESS script, you would see the following:

For `.make(1)`:

```
media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper div {
    margin: 0 Infinity% Infinity% 0;
    width: 94%;
  }
  .wrapper div:nth-child( 1n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

For `.make(2)`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper div {
    margin: 0 6% 6% 0;
    width: 47%;
  }
  .wrapper div:nth-child( 2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

For the case of `.make(1)`, your are getting an error condition in LESS due to `6 / (@count - 1)` which causes a divide by zero error so you see the `Infinity%` value, which is invalid
in CSS.

In that case, the CSS rule for the `div` selector is not totally valid, so the margin values are not what you expect.

You may need to treat the case for `.make(1)` as a special case and hard code the CSS
rule that you need.

You can deal with the special case of one column in LESS using the `default()` function and a gaurd condition (`when`).

See the examples at:

http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default

One way of fixing the LESS/CSS is as follows:

```
.make(1) {
  margin: 0;
}

.make(@count) when (default()) {

  margin: 0 (6 / (@count - 1) * 1%) (6 / (@count - 1) * 1%) 0;
  width: (94 / @count) * 1%;

  &:nth-child(@{count}n)     {margin-right: 0;}

} // make
```

and the results would look like the following: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DeEhK

**Fixing the Bottom Margin Issue**

The bottom issue is a bit trickier.

I would basically set the bottom margin to zero by default and then set the top margin to the desired value.

I would then set the top margin to zero for the top row elements.

For the case of two columns, I might do the following:

```
.make(2) {
  margin: (6 / (2 - 1) * 1%) (6 / (2 - 1) * 1%) 0 0;
  width: (94/2)*1%;
  &:nth-child(2n)    {margin-right: 0;}
  &:nth-child(1)     {margin-top: 0;}
  &:nth-child(2)     {margin-top: 0;}      
}
```

I use the `nth-child({1,2})` to zero out the top margin.

You would need similar rules for the other cases (1,3 and 4 columns).

It is easier to select the top row items then the bottom row items, hence using the top-margin setting is easier than the bottom-margin.

Comment: I have a problem with your margin-top approach. You use 1 and 2 but I can have 3, 4, or more items in the first row. So your approach does not work. Any idea how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to do is add some changes in media query and add classes in HTML. I have paste the changed code it will work fine as per you want.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>CodePen - A Pen by mdmoura</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">    
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div class="temp1"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div class="temp"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div class="temp"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>    
  </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 5%;
    }
.wrapper:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
   }
.wrapper div {
   background-color: green;
   float: left;
   }

.wrapper .temp {
   margin: 0 0 0 0;

   }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper div {
     margin: 0 Infinity% Infinity% 0;
     width: 94%;
   }

 .wrapper .temp {
    margin: 0 Infinity% 0 0;

   }
 .wrapper { background-color: white;}

 .wrapper div:nth-child( 1n) {
   margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
 @media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper div {
   margin: 0 6% 6% 0;
   width: 47%;
  }
 .wrapper div:nth-child( 2n) {
   margin-right: 0;
   }

 .wrapper .temp {
  margin: 0 6% 0 0;    
  }

  }
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper div {
  margin: 0 3% 3% 0;
  width: 31.33333333%;
 }

 .wrapper .temp {
    margin: 0 3% 0 0;    
   }

 .wrapper .temp1 {
    margin: 0 3% 0 0;    
    }


 .wrapper div:nth-child( 3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
   }
 }
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
 .wrapper div {
 margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
 width: 23.5%;
 }
 .wrapper .temp {
   margin: 0 2% 0 0;    
   }
 .wrapper div:nth-child( 4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
  }
 }
 .wrapper div img {
   display: block; 
   max-width: 100%;      
   height: auto;
   outline: 0;
    }
 .clear:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
```